# Why is iron transported across membranes in the ferrous form?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, metabolism, membrane

Iron in the diet of animals is predominantly in the ferric form, but it must be reduced to the ferric form by a specific ferrireductase before it can be transported across the cell membrane into the cell:

> To be absorbed, dietary iron… must be in its ferrous Fe<sup>2+</sup> form. A ferric
> reductase enzyme on the enterocytes’ brush border, duodenal cytochrome
> B (Dcytb), reduces ferric Fe<sup>3+</sup> to Fe<sup>2+</sup>. A protein called divalent
> metal transporter 1 (DMT1), which can transport several divalent
> metals across the plasma membrane, then transports iron across the
> enterocyte’s cell membrane into the cell.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_iron_metabolism)

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 3):

This is not my subject, but from scanning the introductions to a couple of reviews on the general topic of iron metabolism, the following factors seem to be important:

- Ferric iron is less soluble than ferrous iron [1].
- Ferric iron is potentially toxic in the cell because it can be reduced by oxygen, giving reactive oxygen species which are dangerous to the cell [2].

[1] [Srai *et al.* (2002)](https://www.cell.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0092-8674%2802%2901164-9)

[2] [Kaplan (2002)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1521692602900034)

Comment: @John — Thanks for picking up the typo.